# How to access the module of a sub package

Tags: python, package

```
       parent/ 
                __init__.py 
              one/ 
                      __init__.py 
                      module1.py
              two/ 
                      __init__.py 
              three/ 
                      __init__.py
```

From this structure, I want to access module1.py

Accessing `parent.one.module1` didn't work

Comment: Even tried namespace package, didn't help

Comment: @MichaelButscher updated the code

Comment: Explain "didn't work". If there is an error message show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question. Explain from which module you tried to import. Was it the main module (from which you started the program)?

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't add the requested information to your question. Therefore it is too imprecise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access `module1` by importing the following:

```
import parent.one.module1
from parent.one import module1
```

From here, you should be able to reference the assets in `module1`

Let me know if this helps

Comment: @BeenaGates did you try specifically importing the module? What sort of errors are happening. As mentioned before, we need to know what "didn't work" entails